# How to detect whether UIAlertView is currently showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uialertcontroller

Is there any way to judge whether there is currently a `UIAlertView` instance showing? Because it is possible to show multiple `UIAlertView` in the same window level.

```
if ([self isAlertViewShowing]) {
    // do not show UIAlertView again.
} else {
    // show your UIAlertView.
}
```

Hope there is such a method called `isAlertViewShowing` or something else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Method 1-**
Initialize default flag for alert... If alert is not open set isAlertViewShowing as NO

```
    Bool isAlertViewShowing;
    isAlertViewShowing = NO;
    if (isAlertViewShowing == NO){
         UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
         [alert show];
         // Now set isAlertViewShowing to YES
         isAlertViewShowing = YES;
    }
    else
    {
         //Do something
    }
```

**Method  2-**
Make your own function to check whether any `UIAlertView` is showing or not

```
- (BOOL)isAlertViewShowing{
for (UIWindow* window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
    NSArray* subviews = window.subviews;
    if ([subviews count] > 0){
        for (id view in subviews) {
            if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]]) {
                return YES;
            }
        }
    }
}
return NO;
}
```

> I recommended to use second method if number of `UIAlertView` instance
>   may be more than one.

Comment: Does Method 2 also applies to UIAlertController introduced in iOS8?

Comment: you can applies this on any view.Change `UIAlertView` in line number 6 with what kind of view you want to check. Make sure view not view controller.